# can't sorting array's items when enter negative numbers (js)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort array items and I wrote this function. It works if I enter only positive numbers, but when I enter negative numbers it doesn't. Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code?

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  let sort;
  let result = '';
  let array = numbers.split(' ');
  sort = array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else return -1;
  });
  result = sort[sort.length - 1] + ' ' + sort[0];
  console.log(sort);
  console.log(result);
}

highAndLow('3 4 6 8 2 3 5 6 1 0'); // sort: 0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,8
highAndLow('99 8 7 6 5 3 8 9 0 0 1 9'); //sort: 0,0,1,3,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,99
highAndLow('-3 -4 1 9 8 -8 1 2 -11'); //sort: -11,-3,-4,-8,1,1,2,8,9
```

Comment: You can make your sort function one line. array.sort((a,b) => a-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting the numbers as strings, not as, well, numbers.

Use `parseInt` to convert them.

```
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  let sort;
  let result = "";
  let array = numbers.split(" ").map(n => parseInt(n, 10));  // this map makes them numbers
  sort = array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else return -1;
  });
  result = sort[sort.length - 1] + " " + sort[0];
  alert(sort);
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Also you need return 0 when a equals b

Comment: You can also change the comparison function to return `a - b`, this will automatically parse them.

Comment: And also solves the problem of not returning `0` when they're equal.

Comment: thank you everyone , that worked for me also i understood why my code wasn't work  <3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `a - b` in your sort function so that the strings are converted to numbers for sorting.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  let sort;
  let result = '';
  let array = numbers.split(' ');
  sort = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  result = sort[sort.length - 1] + ' ' + sort[0];
  console.log(...sort);
  console.log(result);
}

highAndLow('3 4 6 8 2 3 5 6 1 0');
highAndLow('99 8 7 6 5 3 8 9 0 0 1 9');
highAndLow('-3 -4 1 9 8 -8 1 2 -11');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could omit the mapping and use the delta for sorting. This convert stringed numbers to numbers.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
    let array = numbers
        .split(' ')
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);

    console.log(array[array.length - 1] + ' ' + array[0]);
}

highAndLow('3 4 6 8 2 3 5 6 1 0'); // result: 0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,8
highAndLow('99 8 7 6 5 3 8 9 0 0 1 9'); //result: 0,0,1,3,5,6,7,8,8,9,9,99
highAndLow('-3 -4 1 9 8 -8 1 2 -11'); //result: -11,-3,-4,-8,1,1,2,8,9
```